# Can view keys differentiate between payments and change?

Tags: viewkey, auditing, change

Considering they track incoming payments as well as change, how do they know which one is which? If an organization wants to audit my account, and I've been sending a large number of transfers, won't they see a bunch of incoming transactions that are really just the change of the money I sent?

And will any of this change with RingCT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you think about it, change comes back in the same transaction as the money you sent. If you receive X monero as change, you will have sent Y monero in the same transaction, with Y > X.

The answer to your question boils down to the key images. You give a signed set of key images to the auditor, who can now see money going in and out.

See [How to prove my Monero balance to a world?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/how-to-prove-my-monero-balance-to-a-world/1284#1284) for the procedure.

Nothing about this will change with RingCT.

Comment: So in this sense, key images almost supercede the use of a viewkey.

Comment: If by supercede, you mean supplement, then yes.