# How do I, as a recipient, verify that my transaction actually arrived?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, mymonero, auditing, user-guide

I received some XMR from a service / exchange / friend. How do I verify that my transaction actually arrived?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, theoretical background can be found here:

[Selective transparency in Monero vs Zcash](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2566/selective-transparency-in-monero-vs-zcash)

[Why is the viewkey able to track incoming transactions, but not outgoing transactions?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/why-is-the-viewkey-able-to-track-incoming-transactions-but-not-outgoing-transac)

[Is there any way to construct a transaction manually?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/is-there-any-way-to-construct-a-transaction-manually/2916)

Basically the gist is that you know *a* (the private view key) and *R* (the public tx key). As a result, you are able to compute the shared secret (`aR = D'`) and "decrypt" the transaction.

If you are using the **CLI**, you ought to perform the following steps:

1. In the CLI type `viewkey`, copy the *private / secret* view key.
2. Go to [this](https://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html) tool, which was created by core-team member luigi1111. Furthermore, "Note: this site operates completely on client-side Javascript; no data is ever sent to the web server."
3. Enter your transaction ID / hash in box `1. Transaction Hash:`
4. Enter your *private / secret* view key in box `2. Private Key`
5. Enter your public address in box `3. Recipient's Public Address:`
6. Press on `Check`.
7. If it shows `This address owns output        x with pubkey: y for amount: z` it proves you correctly received your XMR.
8. Note that a typical Monero transaction contains two outputs, of which one goes to the recipient (you) and one goes back to the sender as change. Intuitively, you can only "decrypt" the output that is going to you.

---

If you are using the **GUI**, you ought to perform the following steps:

1. Go to the `Settings` page of the GUI and press on `Show seed & keys`. Subsequently, copy the *private / secret* view key.
2. Go to [this](https://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html) tool, which was created by core-team member luigi1111. Furthermore, "Note: this site operates completely on client-side Javascript; no data is ever sent to the web server."
3. Enter your transaction ID / hash in box `1. Transaction Hash:`
4. Enter your *private / secret* view key in box `2. Private Key`
5. Enter your public address in box `3. Recipient's Public Address:`
6. Press on `Check`.
7. If it shows `This address owns output        x with pubkey: y for amount: z` it proves you correctly received your XMR.
8. Note that a typical Monero transaction contains two outputs, of which one goes to the recipient (you) and one goes back to the sender as change. Intuitively, you can only "decrypt" the output that is going to you.

---

If you are using the **MyMonero**, you ought to perform the following steps:

1. On MyMonero, go to account details.
2. Copy the private view key (called `View Key (Private)` on MyMonero).
3. Go to [this](https://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html) tool, which was created by core-team member luigi1111. Furthermore, "Note: this site operates completely on client-side Javascript; no data is ever sent to the web server."
4. Enter your transaction ID / hash in box `1. Transaction Hash:`
5. Enter your *private / secret* view key in box `2. Private Key`
6. Enter your public address in box `3. Recipient's Public Address:`
7. Press on `Check`.
8. If it shows `This address owns output        x with pubkey: y for amount: z` it proves you correctly received your XMR.
9. Note that a typical Monero transaction contains two outputs, of which one goes to the recipient (you) and one goes back to the sender as change. Intuitively, you can only "decrypt" the output that is going to you.

Comment: Note that when proving to a third party, it is possible to do so more privately and on a per-tx basis without sharing the view secret key by only revealing the shared secret. In the pending [PR-2487](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2487), I propose two types of signatures for proving outgoing and incoming payments without revealing the tx secret key and the view secret key, respectively.

Comment: I am using the GUI but there is no show seed and key, there is only a show seed button...

Comment: It shows 'false' 2 times, what does that mean? (@ mymonero)

Comment: @user4331: You're using an outdated version.

Comment: @nijsjol: This typically means it wasn't correctly sent to your address. Are you sure you followed the guide correctly?

Comment: It show me true and the amount is correct but my GUI balance still 0,
So what happened?

Comment: Use this guide: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance