# Coins Not Appearing (GUI Wallet) - Transaction on Blockchain, Wallet Synced, Cache Deleted

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, balance

Withdrew coins from Bter.com exchange to Monero Wallet GUI, but the balance not appearing in Monero Wallet GUI 11.

- [Transaction on Blockchain](https://moneroblocks.info/search/5faaa10c393d8814949a1ea2d292906e5c92e81882742571015539538c880014)
- Wallet is synced.
- Deleted Wallet Cache

My balance still shows 0.

Help!

Comment: I'm now trying something new... Deleting the database at .bitmonero/lmdb/data.mdb

Comment: Can you first verify whether your transaction actually arrived. You can use this guide: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived

Comment: @dEBRUYNE Yes, the transaction arrived, however Monero Wallet GUI 11 still shows 0 balance.

Comment: If deleting the wallet cache doesn't work, try to restore with the 25 word mnemonic seed. As restore height you can use `1400000`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Magically today it appeared! Simply opened the wallet and before it even finished syncing the balance was there (even though still says syncing). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try [mymonero](https://mymonero.com/#/) first, maybe your local data was not updated.

国人？