# How can i retrieve XMR sent to my Monero wallet without a payment ID?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, payment-id

I withdrew XMR to my Monero wallet, but I didn't use a payment ID as it said it was optional, and I used the receiving address of my wallet which I figured was enough.

Now I can see the funds are withdrawn, and verified with the hash details etc, but can't find any funds in my Monero wallet. When I try to "receive" the funds or search a transaction, it requires I input a payment ID which I don't have....

I'm not sure whether there's still some way to receive the XMR? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which wallet are you using? Also, could you verify that your transaction actually arrived: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived

Comment: i'm using Monero GUI, i couldn't verify the transaction arrived, but i could see evidence it was sent. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You do it the same way you do with a payment ID, since payment ID has no relevance to receiving monero to your wallet.

If you don't see the incoming monero, then your wallet or daemon are probably not fully synced yet. Run "status" in monerod, and make sure it has synced to 100%. Then make sure the wallet has connected to the daemon and finished scanning.

In any case, make sure you use the latest version of the Monero software. If you're using a version prior to 0.11.0.0, it will not be able to fully sync. 0.11.1.0 is the recommended version, as it fixes a couple sync bugs with 0.11.0.0.

You'll have to be clearer as to what requires a payment ID in your second to last paragraph, but I suspect there is no requirement, just an option.

Comment: Thanks for your help! i think the wallet must not be sync'd fully. I will try that and report back.

Comment: Update: after downloading latest version and allowing to fully sync, the funds were present. Thanks again for the help.