# never received monero yet shows on the blockchain?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I bought some Monero using shapeshift, [here](https://xmrchain.net/tx/146086d7d04f05c9e839890dd01323c1902302ed6995368579b56a4b664e28d8) is the transaction on the blockchain,  I entered my private viewkey and my address it actually showed the amount I ordered under the output public key and shows that it is true. I am using windows 10 with the monero gui Current Version: 0.11.1.0 Helium Hydra and have synced it several times but it still shows a nil balance, I also tried entering all the information for the payment into the check payment part of the wallet but get an error saying failed to get transaction from daemon. Please any help here would be greatly appreciated in getting my funds to my wallet. No payment id was used but my understanding is that this does not matter when receiving, it is more to know who has paid you from a personal checking point of view.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to a remote node?

Comment: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived

Comment: @D Haer - Use that ^ guide to resolve your issue.