# Monero GUI hacked? Transaction 'To:' field says "Unknown recipient" & did not receive sent amount in other address

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I've now sent 2 transactions from the Monero GUI to an online wallet over 2 weeks apart, none of the amounts have posted on the online wallet and on both transaction in the 'History' tab both have "Unknown recipient" in the transaction list entry 'To:' field.

It took me a little bit of troubleshooting to notice this.

I entered the other wallet's address on both times, this time I know for sure as I just did it. I checked out this guide (https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/prove-payment.html) and it shows the 'To:' field has the receiving address.

Is my install of the Monero GUI hacked? I downloaded it directly from getmonero.org so I thought it's good.

I am running it in Advanced mode using a remote node/host, and wallet and daemon are fully synchronized.

Comment: Just logged back in and there are no longer any transactions listed in the History tab. I was going to get the transaction ID and payment proof (transaction key) and go into the Advanced > Prove/check tab to look at the blockchain. There's no refresh or reload transactions.

Comment: The 'Check Transaction' form has a 'Signature' field/input box - is this the same value as the payment proof (transaction key)? I got this value by clicking on the 'P' and pasted it in but the 'Check' button does not get enabled.

Comment: Fyi, I was able to get the 'History' tab to show the list of transactions by changing the 'Date from' value to a more recent date - it was showing a date in 2014.

Comment: I removed the input value in the 'Address' input box and the 'Check' button became enabled. When I clicked it, it says 'Bad signature' - the value I put into the 'Signature' field was the 'Payment proof' value I got from clicking on the 'P'. What signature value do I use? The guide (https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/prove-payment.html) doesn't mention this.

Comment: Are the transactions actually present on the blockchain? https://xmrchain.net/ | Also, which version of the GUI are you using?

Comment: Yes, I checked both xmrchain.net and moneroblocks.info and the transactions/blocks are there. I clicked on the 'Prove sending' tab in xmrchain.net and it's asking for the 'Tx private key'. What value is this from? And what value is the signature field asking for?

Comment: I'm using v0.14.0.0 of the GUI.

Comment: How can I check what address the money actually went to? I don't understand why there's a 'Unknown recipient' value in the To Address field.

Comment: Do you have the view key of the recipient wallet? Because then you can simply run this guide -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived

Comment: I logged in and was able to get the view key. Filled the form at https://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html and got these results: 'This address owns output 0 with pubkey' and 'This address doesn't own output 1 with pubkey' in red font. The amount that I sent is in the 'Total received field' and the 'Found payment ID' is a bunch of zeroes.

Comment: Btw, the recipient is a Guarda online wallet. I've clicked on 'Update balance' and 'Load Transactions History' but it still shows a zero balance and no history.

Comment: Can you perhaps contact their support? There may be an issue with their backend due to which the transactions do not properly show in your account.