# General bytes ripped me off?

Tags: mymonero

I used a general bytes atm to purchase xmr today. When I was done it said transaction completed and asked for my number to send a receipt to. I gave my number and it sent me a verification code and asked for it on screen. Well, I pressed a number twice by accident and it didn't send me a receipt like it should have. I then checked my wallet and there is no funds and pending transactions. Is there a way I can use only my address and view key to check to see if there is a pending transaction?  If not, how the hell am I gonna find my $500!

Comment: I've never heard of general bytes, but it sounds like you need to contact them.

Comment: They are actually the second largest bitcoin atm manufacturers in the world. Unfortunately, they are located in tge Czech Republic so I won't likely hear from them tonight.

Comment: 1) suggest you reach out to the ATM company; I'm not sure how anyone here is able to help and 2) please consider rephrasing your question & title; at this stage you do not know if you have been "ripped off" by anyone.

Comment: @StevenRago - can you run this guide? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived