# Help me see if I've accepted Monero

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

[How do I, as a recipient, verify that my transaction actually arrived?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived)

I used this guide to verify that my trade had arrived, but the results were as follows:

This address doesn't own output 0 with pubkey: 18c0b092******fdd6e38d9c4 for amount: Confidential
This address doesn't own output 1 with pubkey: 73f9d450f1d7*******11a575a37 for amount: Confidential

Total received: 0

Did the apparent deal fail to reach my wallet? I asked the customer service of Huobi exchange, and they said that Monero had been sent out, and my balance was 0 when I used the simple mode or connected to the remote node. What should I do? Where's my money?
PS: I used the GUI wallet 015.0.2 Mac version

Comment: Footnote: this transaction took place six months ago, not now, and I've updated the simple mode sync block to the latest, just short of full node run and sync.

Comment: Are you sure you followed the guide correctly? Because that output kind of indicates that the funds were *not* correctly sent to your wallet.