# Missing deposit Monero GUI wallet (bought at an Bitcoin Embassy ATM) and I have tx id. Still cannot find where it is

Tags: txpool

So last night I bought Monero at a local atm and have bought at the same atm with success yet this time it's just not showing up. I've done some research and the transaction id isn't popping up anywhere. Definitely sent to the right address. I don't know... just a little lost

Comment: Can you first verify your transaction? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived

Comment: Please also see the guide I linked. https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance

Comment: ended up figuring out the the atm owner had not update his monero and wasn't conncecting to the node. I appreciate everyones willingingness to help ty!!!\