# My Coins Didn't Arrive/How to "claim" coins

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, balance, remote-node, new-user

I am new to Monero.
Recently I have installed **monero-wallet-cli**
And created wallet with multiple addresses. (**address new**x100)
So then I sent XMR from Binance to one of my addresses with index [56].
It's been almost a day and I still don't see it my account
BTW I am using remote node address as deamon

Did I done something wrong and supposed to use primary account

Comment: Can you verify the transaction first? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived

Comment: Yes, It's there, but how to use it now.
My wallet balance in GUI and monero-wallet-cli is 0(
No matter how many times I have updated.
It's not allowing to send me any

Comment: Did you look at this guide already? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance