# An error occurred while getting decoy outputs: Error: Count cannot be 11

Tags: mymonero

Since my last buy, I get this error when I want to send XMR to friends.

Answer (score 2):

MyMonero is not yet fully updated after the scheduled network upgrade, see:

https://twitter.com/MyMonero/status/1559828547983867905

Thus, I'd recommend to either patiently wait until they release a new version that is compatible with the recent protocol upgrade (I expect a version to be released soon) or you can import your keys into another wallet (e.g. the official CLI/GUI). Let me know if you need any assistance with the latter (in case you choose for this option).

To put your mind at ease, you can verify an incoming transaction with this guide:

[How do I, as a recipient, verify that my transaction actually arrived?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived)